# Sapply different than individual application of function

Tags: r, sapply

When applied individually to each element of the vector, my function gives a different result than using sapply.  It's driving me nuts!

Item I'm using: this (simplified) list of arguments another function was called with:

```
f <- as.list(match.call()[-1])
> f
$ampm
c(1, 4)
```

To replicate this you can run the following:

```
foo <- function(ampm) {as.list(match.call()[-1])}
f <- foo(ampm = c(1,4))
```

Here is my function.  It just strips the 'c(...)' from a string.

```
stripConcat <- function(string) {
    sub(')','',sub('c(','',string,fixed=TRUE),fixed=TRUE)
}
```

When applied alone it works as so, which is what I want:

```
> stripConcat(f)
[1] "1, 4"
```

But when used with sapply, it gives something totally different, which I do NOT want:

```
> sapply(f, stripConcat)
 ampm
[1,] "c" 
[2,] "1" 
[3,] "4"
```

Lapply doesn't work either:

```
> lapply(f, stripConcat)
$ampm
[1] "c" "1" "4"
```

And neither do any of the other apply functions.  This is driving me nuts--I thought lapply and sapply were supposed to be identical to repeated applications to the elements of the list or vector!

Comment: `> dput(f) structure(list(ampm = c(1, 4)), .Names = "ampm")`

Comment: The issue here (which I don't fully understand) is the difference between `as.character(f)` and `as.character(f[[1]])`. Try `sapply(as.character(f),stripConcat)`.

Comment: This almost gets there! It gives the right answer, but removes the element's name: `> sapply(as.character(f), stripConcat) c(1, 4) "1, 4" ` whereas previously the "1,4" element was named "ampm".

Comment: I requested some help from more experienced experts in the R chat room. If you're patient, I'm certain someone will pop up with an explanation and a possible work around within a few hours at least. In the meantime, I'm going to delete several of my preceding comments, as my edit makes them unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for all your help joran!

Comment: well, `lapply` output at least matches correctly to `stripConcat(f[[1]])`

Comment: I've developed a little work-around where I do as joran suggested, calling `f2 <- sapply(as.character(f),stripConcat)` and then assigning `names(f2) <- names(f)`.  If there's a more elegant way that'd be great, but this will hold me for now.  Thanks all!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code? It's unlikely that text manipulation on language objects is what you really want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discrepency you are seeing, I believe, is simply due to how as.character coerces elements of a list.

```
x2 <- list(1:3, quote(c(1, 5)))
as.character(x2)
[1] "1:3"     "c(1, 5)"

lapply(x2, as.character)
[[1]]
[1] "1" "2" "3"

[[2]]
[1] "c" "1" "5"
```

`f` is not a call, but a list whose first element is a call.

```
is(f)
[1] "list"   "vector"
as.character(f)
[1] "c(1, 4)"

> is(f[[1]])
[1] "call"     "language"
> as.character(f[[1]])
[1] "c" "1" "4"
```

`sub` attempts to coerce anything that is not a character into a chracter.
When you pass sub a list, it calls `as.character` on the `list`.
When you pass it a call, it calls `as.character` on that `call`.

---

It looks like for your `stripConcat` function, you would *prefer* a list as input.

In that case, I would recommend the following for that function:

```
stripConcat <- function(string) {
    if (!is.list(string))
      string <- list(string)
    sub(')','',sub('c(','',string,fixed=TRUE),fixed=TRUE)
}
```

Note, however, that *string* is a misnomer, since it doesn't appear that you are ever planning to pass `stripConcat` a string. (not that this is an issue, of course)

Comment: you should probably add that assuming that's correct input, the fix is to call `deparse` inside OP's function

Comment: @eddi, I was just adding a point about fixing the function, but I wouldn't go with `deparse`.

Comment: @eddi, sorry I missed your comment about "assuming the correct input" - in which case, yep makes sense.   I meant that the main issue from the OP is passing the wrong kind of input and hence, I would check for the input within the function